# Why am i getting incorrect values when i fetchone() why writing in SQLite?

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE CPU=CPU")
for i in range(3):
    print(c.fetchone())
```

This returns:

> ('...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', 'CPU', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...')
>   ('...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', 'TEST', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...')
>   ('...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', 'TEST', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...')

I don't understand why I am getting the bottom two rows when CPU does not equal CPU for them...

Answer (score 3):

`CPU=CPU` is the issue here. This is because a *non-null* column in SQL is always equal to itself. So your query will return everything from the table that does not have a null value in the `CPU` column.

The fix is to wrap the string `'CPU'` around the quotes it needs, as follows:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE CPU='CPU'")
for i in range(3):
    print(c.fetchone())
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: "a column in SQL is always equal to itself" Unless it is `NULL`. Hate to nitpick, but `NULL=NULL` returns false (really it returns unknown, but it's easier to think in 2-value logic).

Comment: @mypetlion, that's far from nitpicking! It's a vital piece of information I failed to mention. I'll edit the answer to reflect that. Thank you!